# Loading osmdroid MapView in a new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-mapview, osmdroid

Loading of the map in my application was slow on some devices. I wanted to load the map in a different thread and show a progress dialog until it is done.

I found this article: http://pygmalion.nitri.de/android-starting-an-activity-containing-a-mapview-takes-forever-380.html

I think that the only thing it does is waiting for defined time and then run the code inside the run() method. That's not what I want.

I tried to use ASyncTask with the same XML layout as in the article above:

- in doInBackground()

  - created MapView by `new MapView(MyActivity.this);`
  - setters for multitouch, zoom controls, tilesource (offline with osmbonusback)
- in onPostExecute()

  - added mapview to the prepared FrameLayout

The map loaded correctly but the zoom coontrols were on the top of the screen. Also when I zoomed in, the tiles got rescaled instead of loading the correct zoom level tiles - until I moved the map.

Is there any way to open the activity instantly, wait for the map and let the user know it is loading?

Comment: "Loading of the map in my application was slow" can you tell us what exatly was slow? internetconnection and downlloding map data is slow and already performed in background threads

Comment: I use offline maps. By the slow loading I mean the time between the user moves to the activity and the activity is fully loaded.

Comment: I have the same issue when using mapsfoge offline maps because translation from mapsforge format to tile-pngs requires a lot of processing. the generated tile-pngs will be cached so next time rendering is much faster. perhaps (mapsforge-)cache-dir is not set or invalid on the slow devices? are you using mapsforge offline maps? if no i have no experience with other osmdroid offline formats

Comment: nope I'm not using mapsforge maps

Comment: then i cannot help you directly. just a clue: set         `OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.DEBUG_TILE_PROVIDERS = true;  OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.DEBUGMODE = true;` so you get more detailed debug output